# Alert box freezes on the simulator after if statement

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

This is a follow up from my previous question

I have this code

basically its meant to when the timer reaches you get a message box saying well done ect and then the screen resets and you get to play again, all the images reset and the start button re appears but you cant clear the alert box its just frozen on the sim,  am i missing something out here?

heres the code

```
if (MainInt <= 0)
    {
        [timer invalidate];
        timelabel.text = @"5";

        [startbutton setHidden:NO];


        CGRect frame = [player frame];
        frame.origin.x = 137.0f;
        frame.origin.y = 326.0;
        [player setFrame:frame];

        CGRect frame2 = [enemy frame];
        frame2.origin.x = 90.0f;
        frame2.origin.y = 20.0;
        [enemy setFrame:frame2];

        CGRect frame3 = [enemy2 frame];
        frame3.origin.x = 210.0f;
        frame3.origin.y = 20.0;
        [enemy2 setFrame:frame3];

        UIAlertView *alert1 = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"GRATZ" message:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"Congratulations you made it to Level : %d Now try then next level" ,fred] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil];


        [alert1 show];
        [alert1 release];

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are creating more than one and putting them all on top of each other.

Try resetting your `MainInt = 5;` like you were with your `timeLabel.text` in your previous question

Comment: This works (now i can close the message box but everything is still running in the back ground, can i email you my code and you can have a look because i feel i may be looping everywhere and its a mess, theres only about 50 lines so should be to much of a hassel?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't mind answering questions, but code reviewing sounds like I should be getting paid for it.

Comment: haha no worries cheers for the help anyway much appreciated ( I looked at your angry Gran app seems like many hours went into that)